# Lectures notes on international trade

Tags: international-trade, international-economics, comparative-advantage

do you have any lecture notes covering the theories of international trade (Ricardian models, HOS, Melitz...)? I have a master in quantitative econ so I'd be happy to have both basic references and more quantitative ones.

Thanks!